# Парсинг сайта с переходом по внутренним ссылкам с помощью python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

уважаемые разработчики! Помогите пожалуйста решить следующую задачу:
имеется список улиц на сайте https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/aef2c735-2e21-42e5-8638-9667bade6a2b/

1. необходимо скопировать наименование улицы, далее перейти по внутренней ссылке, которая содержится в теге href="..." каждой улицы
2. после перехода скопировать номера домов, относящиеся к этой улице
3. поместить полученные данные в excel

код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

HOST = "https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/"
URL = "https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/aef2c735-2e21-42e5-8638-9667bade6a2b/"
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0'
}

resp = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
streets_results = soup.find("div", class_="row")

file_adress = load_workbook("форма запроса.xlsx")
sheet_file_adress = file_adress.active
streets_fias  = load_workbook("streets_fias.xlsx")
sheet_streets_fias = streets_fias.active
df_streets = pd.read_excel("streets_fias.xlsx")


streets = ["Название улицы"]
for streets_tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    streets.append(streets_tag.text)
    df_streets = pd.DataFrame(streets)

df_streets.to_excel("streets_fias.xlsx")
```

Улицы собрать получилось. Использую pandas для сбора во фрейм улиц, и выгрузку их в excel. Но затрудняюсь с переходом по внутренним ссылкам, которые содержатся в названии улиц в теге href и в том, как в дальнейшем сопоставить каждый дом с улицей, на которой он расположен, так как на выходе нужно получить таблицу вида:

| Название улицы | Номер дома |
| --- | --- |
| 25 Декабря Улица | 1 |
| 25 Декабря Улица | 10 |
| 25 Декабря Улица | .... |
| ... | ... |
| Ямская Улица | 1 |
| Ямская Улица | ... |
| Ямская Улица | Сооружение 500 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набросал небольшой многопоточный скриптик, чтобы 10 лет не ждать выполнения.
Улица и дома вносятся в словарь streets_houses_dict, где ключ - улица, а значение - список из домов.
После выполнения остается разобрать этот словарь в excel.

UPD У некоторых улиц на странице отсутствуют дома, поэтому некоторые значения ключей это пустые списки. Если такие значения не нужны, то их легко убрать прописав условие

```
if len(houses_list) == 0:
    return
```

после houses_list.append(i.string) (прописывать вне for)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading

url = "https://фиас.онлайн/aef2c735-2e21-42e5-8638-9667bade6a2b/"
base_url = "https://фиас.онлайн"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

streets = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-md-3")

streets_houses_dict = {}


def get_houses(street_name, street_url):
    response = requests.get(street_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    houses = soup.find_all("table")[1].find_all("td")[1].find_all("a")
    houses_list = []

    for i in houses:
        houses_list.append(i.string)

    streets_houses_dict[street_name] = houses_list


def async_get_houses():
    threads_list = []

    for street in streets:
        street_name = street.find("a").text.split(" ")[0]
        street_url = street.find("a").get("href")
        get_street_houses = threading.Thread(
            target=get_houses, args=(street_name, base_url + street_url)
        )
        get_street_houses.start()

        threads_list.append(get_street_houses)

    for t in threads_list:
        t.join()


async_get_houses()
```